# Summer time calculation

Tags: date, datetime

Currently i have missing understand on summertime, below is my context:

```
start summer time: June/1/2014 0h
end summer time:   November/29/2014 0h
```

assume at the time 23h59 of November/29/2014 after passing => 0h00 November/30/2014 => the summertime will be minus 1 (-1) => **23h00 of November/29/2014** => it still under summer time (June/1/2014 0h - November/29/2014 0h)

So is my calculation above correct ?

Comment: Change from/to summertime often done at hours away from midnight, just for this reason. http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your misunderstanding is ignoring the fact that *the time zone is part of the timestamp*, and is necessary to make a timestamp in local time unambiguous.

If summer time ends at 00:00 at the beginning of November 30th, then the series of timestamps is:

2014-11-29 23:59:58 XST
2014-11-29 23:59:59 XST
2014-11-29 23:00:00 XWT
2014-11-29 23:01:01 XWT
[...]
2014-11-29 23:59:59 XWT
2014-11:30 00:00:00 XWT

(where "XST" is the summer timezone and "XWT" is the winter timezone). "2014-11-29 23:00:00 XST" and "2014-11-29 23:00:00 XWT" are two different times, one hour apart.

If you are given a local time between 2014-11-29 23:00 and 2014-11-30 00:00 *without* an indicator of whether it's XST or XWT, then it's impossible to turn it into a unique timestamp.